# How to scale view with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I use the code below to scale my view when event happen. But I want the view to be enlarged or reduced with animation not directly see the scaled result. How can I achieve that effect?

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use UIViewAnimations

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); 

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a block animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor) 
}];
```

Comment: Actually, I try this in a coverflow in the delegate method (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel. I want to enlarge the current view. But this code is not work. I can not figure out the reason.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code it is difficult to say why it is not working. Are you sure the animation is being run on the main thread? And does the view scale, but just without the animation, or does it not scale at all?

Comment: Try to make sure it is running in the main thread. dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // insert animation code });